# Как исправить проблему с материалом Покрытие, которое показало ошибку в серч консоли https://pvh-membrany.ru/?

Tags: битрикс

Как исправить проблему с материалом Покрытие, которое показало ошибку в серч консоли https://pvh-membrany.ru/?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по линку - странички больше нет такой, потому и ругается, наверно

Comment: Что нужно сделать чтоб не ругалось?

Comment: проверить - действительно ли этот линк существует. Если нет - значит где-то в сео прописан может...потому и ругается